# MLE and log MLE

Tags: logarithms, maximum-likelihood

I'm getting confused on likelihoods and the use of the log function.

negloglik = negative log likelihood

This statement on negloglik seems to be wrong to me:

"
negloglik is an exponential scale, therefore small changes in negloglik represent a very large change in likelihood.
"

Can anyone explain why it's true? The opposite seems to be the case if you ask me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L(x)$ denote the likelihood function and $N(x) = -\ln L(x)$ be the negative log of the likelihood function.

What happens to $L(x)$ if $N(x)$ is changed to $N(x) + \epsilon$? We get $L(x) = e^{-N(x)}$ so if $N'(x) = N(x) + \epsilon$ we get
$$
L'(x)
 = e^{-N'(x)} = e^{-N(x)-\epsilon}
 = \frac{L(x)}{e^\epsilon}.
$$

So for example

- if $\epsilon = 0.1$ then $L'(x) \approx 0.9 L(x)$,
- and if $\epsilon = 0.001$ then $L'(x) \approx 0.999 L(x)$,
- but if $\epsilon = 1$ then $L'(x) \approx 0.36 L(x)$.

Not sure if this is big enough or not...

**UPDATE**

Your specific example, if $L(x)$ goes from $0.1$ to $0.3$, then $N(x)$ goes from $2.3$ to $1.2$, more than 4 times the size of change in $L(x)$.

Comment: So the statement is incorrect?

Comment: and by "large change" it's meant in an absolute way..

Comment: @1233023 depends on the context, see the actual numbers at the end

Comment: Say I have a likelihood of 0.1 and a likelihood of 0.3. The absolute difference here is 0.2. If I take the negative log to each of these numbers then the absolute difference between those two is larger right? Because log is a convex function on the interval (0,1)..

Comment: @1233023 see the update, you are correct

Comment: Thanks for reality checking me!

Comment: @1233023 you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The general statement is perhaps inaccurate, as the effect is indeed dependent on the specific case. However, remember that the likelihood can (and it does in many cases) take values greater than one. Therefore it is not correct to say that the opposite is true.